# About Java ProcessBuilder's stream

Tags: java, stream, processbuilder

first of all.. apologize what i can't upload code..

(thirdparty program is sdelete)

I'm work with third Party program on java `ProcessBuilder`.

like..

```
ProcessBuilder("cmd","/C","thirdParty.exe")
```

or

```
ProcessBuilder("thirdParty.exe");
```

and then.. I make two thread that using scanner that get `ProcessBuilder`'s stream.
(one is input Stream print , other one is error Stream print)

When I execute this program.

It seems like fine at opening part. `thirdParty` program's opening Messages show up in console and .. according to priority.. `Process` percentage must show up, but doesn't..

Percentage not show up, but it's not hangs or frozzen..

`thirdparty` work's fine. Just Scanner can't get `InputStream` data.
(if not with java process, namely if i just execute program.. percentage show up properly)

and.. finally when `thirdParty` process finished.. all of percentage data show up at once!

is anyone know about this phenomenon?

advice please..

Comment: I'm not sure `Scanner` is a good choice for this, as it could be waiting for a new line character, which not all processes send.  `InputStream` might be better and read each character individually

Comment: You know you can redirect the `ProcessBuilder`'s error stream into the input stream, making it easier to manage ;)

Comment: thank's for advice. i've modify code errorstream redirect to inputStream :) and.. scanner to InputStream :) .. but still percentage show up at once when finished.. T-T

Comment: This could be a buffering issue at the executables end and may not be solvable...

Comment: MadProgrammer // Can you tell me more detail or reference?

Comment: Python, for example, is known to do this...